# Disable SWT Button highlighting and selection

Tags: swt

How can I achieve an SWT **[Button](https://help.eclipse.org/kepler/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fapi%2Forg%2Feclipse%2Fswt%2Fwidgets%2FButton.html)** which does *not* get highlighted on mouse hover nor clicks?

I tried to cancel the **`SWT.HOT`**, **`SWT.SELECTED`** and **`SWT.FOCUSED`** bits on the `detail` attribute of several SWT events, but achieved nothing.

Eg.:

```
swtButton.addListener(SWT.PaintEvent, (e) -> {
    e.detail &= ~SWT.SELECTED;
    e.detail &= ~SWT.HOT;
    e.detail &= ~SWT.FOCUSED;
});
```

Comment: I don't think this is possible.

Comment: Ok, thank you Greg.